# Github api returns bad credentials even with oauth token

Tags: github, oauth, github-api, github-oauth

update: even such a request get bad credential ==>

```
curl -H "Authorization: token [token]" https://api.github.com
```

===============

I made a request for GitHub OAuth like this in my iOS app:

```
URL: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize,
params: client_id: ****, redirect_uri: app_url, scope: "repo", state: "0"
```

After redirection from Safari I get a code. I need to access to two things:

1. User data, like email and etc. Also updating user data.
2. List of repositories and commits in public and private repos.

I make following requests:

URL: https://api.github.com/user, get and patch
    Header: Authorization: token [code]

```
URL: https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:repoName
Header: Authorization: token [code]
```

But unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
401, Unauthorized
{
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is said in this blob (NOT the main documentation) you have to exchange token (which is temporary) with a bearer token via this api:

[the main api](https://github.com/github/developer.github.com/blob/master/content/v3/oauth.md#parameters)

Here comes the documentation for others:
[Github blob documentation](https://github.com/github/developer.github.com/blob/master/content/v3/oauth.md)

Comment: Can you/someone give some supporting code snippet and clarification on this answer

Answer (score 4):

The following curl command works:
curl -u your_git_name:your_personal_access_token https://api.github.com/user